# runtime error on softkeyboard using LatinIME.git example

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I need help from someone of professional android developers.
I develop softkeyboard for android 2.2. I wanted to use LatinIME.git as example.

An Eclipse project is correct and can be compiled, but after installing app and setting keyboard as input method on device(I use HTC Desire on 2.2) I have a runtime error:

```
10-13 16:31:03.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 16:31:03.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4917): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-13 16:31:03.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4917):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
10-13 16:31:03.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4917):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-13 16:31:03.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4917):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
10-13 16:31:03.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4917):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
10-13 16:31:03.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4917):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
10-13 16:31:03.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4917):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
10-13 16:31:03.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4917):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
10-13 16:31:03.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4917):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
10-13 16:31:03.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4917):     at com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME.onCreateCandidatesView(LatinIME.java:410)
10-13 16:31:03.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4917):     at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindowInner(InputMethodService.java:1317)
10-13 16:31:03.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4917):     at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindow(InputMethodService.java:1285)
10-13 16:31:03.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4917):     at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService$InputMethodImpl.showSoftInput(InputMethodService.java:388)
```

...
After force closing keyboard works but KeyboardView  is showing something wrong please see pictures:

[image]

**Latin1.png**

[image]

**Latin2.png**

Thanks a lot.

Best Regards, Vitaliy.

Comment: Let's see your `PhoneLayoutInflater.java` code.

Answer (score 0):

Error is on parsing xml:

> on the line